# Как переставить слова, чтобы понятно было, кто на ком стоял?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, порядок-слов

> Приятно думать, что «туристический налог» – два евро в день, который
>   взимается со всякого туриста, – идёт на благое дело.

Скобок хотелось бы избежать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, так:

Приятно думать, что «туристический налог», который взимается со всякого туриста, два евро в день, идёт на благое дело.

Можно и с тире, но конструкция становится тяжелее:

*Приятно думать, что «туристический налог», который взимается со всякого туриста, - два евро в день - идёт на благое дело.*

А повтор "туристический" - "с туриста" не напрягает? Можно убрать:

*Приятно думать, что два евро в день налога, который взимается со всякого туриста, идут на благое дело.*

Comment: Люси! Два евро - в день налога! Ржунимагу! Но помогли, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:  Приятно думать, что «туристический налог» – два евро в день, **которые взимаются** со всякого туриста, – идёт на благое дело.

Comment: Спасибо! Но я выданную ЛОшечку стесняюся отбирать... Не пойму, почему никто не ставит "пятёрку" за вопрос: я всем ответившим, даже и мало помогшим, лайкаю ответ - за уделённое мне время...